# Microsoft Security Essentials API

Tags: api, sdk, antivirus, ms-security-essentials

I'm looking for an API or SDK or any other option to integrate with Microsoft Security Essentials.
I want to be able to get information such as when was the last update or scan? and to be able to do these actions from my component.

Any information at all would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.  You could probe the windows security centre to check that it is running and scanning is enabled: [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/windowssecurity/thread/bd97d9e6-75c1-4f58-9573-9009df5de19b).

However direct access to the Antivirus APIs requires an NDA (so I'm told) from M$ because of obvious security issues...  I might ask why you need this access?  The security centre has these capabilities in a UI.  If you need lots of control, you really need to move to a security product designed for an enterprise that will have these capabilities already.